# Azure Resource Group Sharing

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

I was wondering if someone could help. Is it possible to share resource groups between azure subscriptions;

A little bit of background, I have two subscriptions in azure under one tenant, I am after setting up a VPN between each of the subscriptions, however I am yet to find a solution that doesn't involve sharing a resource group to allow connections.

With this in mind, is it possible to share resource groups between subscriptions or does it have to be in the same subscription?

If this is the case, how would I go about setting up a VPN between subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Resource groups have nothing to do with using or connecting services. They're just an organizational (and security) boundary for viewing/configuring/changing resource settings, deleting resources, etc. Resource Groups are specific to a given subscription.

There's absolutely nothing stopping you from connecting services across subscriptions, as long as you know the passwords/access tokens/certificates/etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot share resource groups across subscriptions (not that it makes sense in the first place). You can either create a [site-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal) or (better) [create a peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#create-a-peering) between virtual networks across the subscriptions.

Peerings are free, easy to setup and don't require any management. Peerings work cross subscriptions and cross tenants (as of november 2019 afaik).

Comment: Thanks, Are we able to define the traffic that comes into the peering and then redirect it to a secuded part of the network, or will they have complete access?

Comment: you can use NSG to allow\disallow traffic inside vnet (including peering\site-to-site)