# Azure VMs in different locations

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Is it possible to create VMs in a different location but in the same resource group?
**Eg One VM will in West Europe and the other in East US**

Comment: A Resource Group is an organizational tool for grouping things together and setting security boundaries. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018341/272109) where I talk about this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, yes.

A [resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal#what-is-a-resource-group) is a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The resource group can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group. You decide how you want to allocate resources to resource groups based on what makes the most sense for your organization. Generally, add resources that share the same lifecycle to the same resource group so you can easily deploy, update, and delete them as a group.

The resource group stores metadata about the resources. Therefore, when you specify a location for the resource group, you are specifying where that metadata is stored. For compliance reasons, you may need to ensure that your data is stored in a particular region.

The resources in a resource group can be located in different regions than the resource group. And you can even move a resource from one resource group to another.

The other factors that can help in defining your resource group are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#resource-groups) in detail.